# DateTimeSensor Monday to Friday at given time

Tags: branch

Good afternoon,

I try to create a program with branch operators, using airflow.

Each branch should have its own schedule.

Some branches should run Monday to Friday, others from Tuesday to Saturday, at a scheduled time.

For dags, I can use the crontab syntax, e.g. `"00 08 * * 2-6"`.

I'm new with branch operators, so I don't really understand, how this works.

I think, that I schedule the dag to `"00 06 * * 1-6"` and the branches should wait until the time, they should run.

Can I also use the crontab syntax for the branches?

Can somebody give me a hint, how to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards

Rolf

```
cond1 = BranchDateTimeOperator(
    task_id='datetime_branch',
    follow_task_ids_if_true=['date_in_range'],
    follow_task_ids_if_false=['date_outside_range'],
    target_upper=datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 10, 15, 0, 0),
    target_lower=datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 10, 14, 0, 0),
    dag=dag,
)
```

But, I don't really understand, how this would do, what I want.
So, how could I define, that it should run Monday to Friday, or Tuesday to Saturday?
When it's outside the range, how should I wait and come back, when the time is reached?

`airflow.sensors.date_time`

--> [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/date_time/index.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

Same question on how to define the weekdays, when it should run.

I need a dag, which is started at 6am and its branches waits until their time (one should run at 7am, one at 7:30am, on at 7:45am, etc.
Important is, that some of the branches should run Monday to Friday and others Tuesday to Saturday.